# RST_STREAM with code 9 getting error on server

Tags: nestjs

It happen for backend nest-js application which uses GRPC service.

Need solution for that. Don't know why that issue getting on server. anyone knows anything about that issue please feel free to help out from that.

I don't understand why this happened suddenly.